# Vuforia iOS Books Sample Using offline database

Tags: ios, vuforia

I have been trying to change the implementation of the book sample to use the offline target database (stone and chips) from ImageTarget sample. I hope

someone can post any guidance on how to proceed. In anycase, I'm trying to copy the loadObjectTrackerDataSet implementation from ImageTargetsViewController into BooksViewController. I hit a roadblock though: "Expected unqualified-id". Please see attached screenshot for details.

[image: Build error]

Any ideas is well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard. I saw the problem. I missed a closing bracket.